# Return values of my stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, join

I used stored procedures to optimize queries of my sql script.This is a script to update the tables of my database when i excute it I have no errors in the same time I have no result. how can i return values of my stored procedures??

Here is my script:

```
        DELIMITER |

        CREATE PROCEDURE data_table1_test()

        BEGIN

        DROP TEMPORARY  TABLE IF EXISTS ch.table1;

        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ch.table1
        SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
        SOITAB.champ1 as champ1,
        CONCAT(SOITAB.champ1,' ',SOITAB.fk_champcam ) as champ1_cam,SOITAB.champup as champup,
        supM(CASE WHEN (SOITAB.fk_champsois IN (8,11,12,14,18,19,20,47,51)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(DISTINCT CSSTAB.champicss) as champqtr,
        supM(CASE WHEN (SOITAB.fk_champsois In (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,11,12,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,47,51))
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(DISTINCT CSSTAB.champicss) as champqtn,
        CTAB.champidcam as champidcam,
        CTAB.champna as champna, 
        CTAB.champuk as champuk,
        CTAB.champst as champst,
        CTAB.champet as champet,
        CTAB.champiden as champiden,
        CTAB.champdeba as champdeba,
        CSTAB.champids as champids,
        CSTAB.champcat as champcat,
        CSTAB.champop as champop,
        CSTAB.champshco as champshco,
        CSTAB.champxc as champxc,
        LEFT(CSTAB.champxc,2) as champscon,
        CSTAB.champdowe as champdowe,
        CSTAB.fk_caogst as sht,
        CSTAB.pr as pr,
        CCTAB.champidcc as champidcc,
        CCTAB.champna as p_champna,
        CCTAB.champdes as pchampdes,
        CCTAB.fk_ca_br,
        MAX(LEFT(CCTAB.note,3)) AS bu,
        GROUP_CONCAT(champspn, ' by ',FORMAT(CSSTAB.qu,0)  ORDER BY champspn ASC SEPARATOR ' + ') as sup_champ1,
        supm(distinct(CSSTAB.npp*CSSTAB.qu)) AS champpfi,
        CsupTAB.champna as sup_champna,
        CsupTAB.id_champcsu as sup_id,
        CsupTAB.champiden as sup_champiden,
        CCDTAB.champidcc as champidcc,
        CCDTAB.ct1 as pct1,
        CCDTAB.ct2 as pct2,
        COUNT(distinct CSSTAB.champicss) as champseti,ch.PVGTAB.pv as pv, 
        supm(distinct(CSSTAB.npp*CSSTAB.qu)) AS npp,CHCTAB.p as p, 
        max(SOITAB.champcat) as lod

        FROM bdata.champsoit SOITAB

        LEFT OUTER JOIN bdata.champcsi CSTAB ON CSTAB.champ1 = SOITAB.champ1 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN bdata.champcam CTAB ON SOITAB.fk_champcam = CTAB.champidcam
        LEFT OUTER JOIN bdata.champcsi_set CSSTAB ON CSSTAB.fk_champcsi = CSTAB.champids
        LEFT OUTER JOIN bdata.champccco CCTAB ON CSTAB.fk_champccco = CCTAB.champidcc
        LEFT OUTER JOIN bdata.champcccohcca CCHCTAB ON CCTAB.champidcc = CCHCTAB.fk_champccco
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ch.champccde CCDTAB ON CCHCTAB.fk_c_cat= ch.CCDTAB.champidcc
        LEFT OUTER JOIN bdata.champcamhch CHCTAB ON CHCTAB.fk_champccco = CCTAB.champidcc
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ch.champpv PVGTAB on ch.PVGTAB.url = CCTAB.champidcc
        LEFT OUTER JOIN bdata.champcsu CsupTAB ON CCTAB.fk_champcsu = CsupTAB.id_champcsu

        WHERE CSTAB.champstat = 'active' AND CCTAB.champetap = 1 AND CCHCTAB.is_primary = '1'
        GROUP BY SOITAB.champ1,SOITAB.fk_champcam;

        END |
        DELIMITER;


        #####################champpgrte###############################################

        DELIMITER |
        CREATE PROCEDURE data_table2_test()
        BEGIN

        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS ch.table2;
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ch.table2

        SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN

        champspete.champ1,
        supM(champspete.champqtn) as champqtn ,
        supM(champspete.champqtr) as champqtr, 
        count(distinct champspete.campaign_id) as champscam, 
        champspete.sup_champna, 
        champspete.lod

        FROM ch.champspete 

        GROUP BY ch.champspete.champ1;
        ALTER TABLE ch.champpgrte ADD INDEX (champ1);
        END |
        DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Well, actually you don't select anything. You're creating temporary tables with the data from the select statement. Nothing more.

Comment: First, thank u for ur answer , I want to update my database and I don't know what should i write to return values ​​of my procedures.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OUT parameter in procedure.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE CountOrderByStatus(
 IN orderStatus VARCHAR(25),
 OUT total INT)
BEGIN
 SELECT count(orderNumber)
 INTO total
 FROM orders
 WHERE status = orderStatus;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Calling procedure

```
CALL CountOrderByStatus('Shipped',@total);
SELECT @total;
```

Comment: It  just puts the fields there's no rows because the temporary table has not recognized "unknown table 'table1'"